# vb.net New line in string paragraph

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm going to break line in a paragraph.

Is there such thing as `\n` break the line in string?

```
Dim info As String = "Page name \n Date and Time" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss") & "\n Printed By Admin"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **vbLf**

```
Dim info As String = "Page name " & vbLf & " Date and Time" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss") & "" & vbLf & " Printed By Admin"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Environment.NewLine`

```
Dim info As String = "Page name " & Environment.NewLine _
                     & " Date and Time" _
                     & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss") _
                     & Environment.NewLine & " Printed By Admin"
```

Or [XML literals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384629.aspx) with [Embed Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384752.aspx) in it

```xml
Dim info As String = <info>
Page name
Date and Time <%= DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss") %> 
Printed By Admin
</info>.Value
```

Or if you creating string in the loop then you can use `StringBuilder`

```
Dim info As New StringBuilder()
info.AppendLine("Page name")
info.Append("Date and Time ")
info.AppendLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd, HH:mm:ss"))
info.AppendLine("Printed By Admin")
```

Method `.AppendLine("text")` will add `Environment.NewLine` at the end of the given string